# Method only works when named "update()"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have `bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()`.

then I create and add new_bullets with the Bullet class to the sprite group

```
new_bullet = Bullet(self)
self.bullets.add(new_bullet)
```

Then in the `run_game` method I call `self.bullets.update()` where `.update()` is part of the `Bullet` class. This all works but if I change that method to anything but `update()`. that method is never called in Bullet class and I get errors complaining about update not being apart of bullets which makes since, because it's not? only `new_bullets` is.

Why and how does this work? Why can I only call that method `update()` for it to work properly?

I know `new_bullet` is an instance of the class `Bullet` and would have access to the method `update()`, but not `bullets`, it's only a sprite group.

`bullet.py`

---

```
class Bullet(Sprite):
    """A class to manage bullets fired from the shil"""
    def __init__(self,ai_game):
       """Create a bullet object at the ships current position"""
       super().__init__()
       self.screen = ai_game.screen
       self.settings = ai_game.settings
       self.color = self.settings.bullet_color
       #create a bullet rect at (0, 0) and the set correct position.
       self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.settings.bullet_width,self.settings.bullet_height)
       self.rect.midtop = ai_game.ship.rect.midtop

       #store the bullets position as a decimal value
       self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def update_position(self):
        """Move the bullet"""
        # Update the decimal position of t he bullet.
        self.y -= self.settings.bullet_speed
        #update the rect position.
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bullet(self):
        """Draw the bullet to the scree."""
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color,self.rect)
```

`main.py`

---

```
class AlienInvasion:
    """Return the sum of x and y."""
    def __init__(self):
        """ Class to manage game assests and behavior"""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        # Full screen code below
        # self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        # self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
        # self.settings.screen_height = self.screen.get_rect().height

        # windowed code below
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, 
                                               self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Alien Invasion')
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

    def _check_events(self):
        """ Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)

    def _check_keyup_events(self,event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            #Move the ship to the right
            self.ship.moving_right = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            #Move the ship to the right
            self.ship.moving_left = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            #Move the ship to the right
            self.ship.moving_up = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            #Move the ship to the right
            self.ship.moving_down = False

    def _check_keydown_events(self,event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            #Move the ship to the right
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            #Move the ship to the right
            self.ship.moving_left = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            #Move the ship to the right
            self.ship.moving_up = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            #Move the ship to the right
            self.ship.moving_down = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self._fire_bullet()

    def _fire_bullet(self):
        """Create a new bullet and add it to the group"""
        new_bullet = Bullet(self)
        self.bullets.add(new_bullet)
        print(self.bullets)

    def _update_screen(self):
        """Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen."""
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()
        pygame.display.flip()

    def run_game(self):
        """ Method handles running the game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self._update_screen()
            self.ship.track_ship_movement()
            self.bullets.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

Comment: "then in the run_game method I call self.bullets.update() where .update() is part of the Bullet class." No, it isn't; it's part of the Group class, defined for you by Pygame.

Comment: Its actually in both classes, the `pygame.sprite.Sprite()` class has a method called `update()` which is a [placeholder](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.update), the `pygame.Sprite.Group()` class also has a method called `update()` which calls `.update()` on every sprite it contains.

Comment: Did you try [reading the documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html)?

Comment: Yeah I tried and its a little difficult to find what I want, I have a book as well that I'm following and what you said is what I read, but I don't follow how the sprite update() knows of  the Bullet update(). So the Sprite.Group placeholder update looks through the enitire code for a method called update then calls it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've become confused by the fact that two different classes have `update` methods. That name isn't something magical, it's just part of the API for those classes.

Here's a simpler example that works with different names, so that it is more clear:

```
class MyContainer: # this is a standin for a pygame Group
    def __init__(self, *objects):
        self.objects = objects

    def foo(self):
        for obj in self.objects:
            obj.bar() # call a specific method on each object

class MyObject: # this is a standin for a pygame Sprite
    def bar(self):    # the class has the method called by MyContainer.foo
        print("Bar!")

class InvalidObject:  # this is not going to work if put in MyContainer
    def baz(self):
        pass
```

This will work:

```
c = MyContainer(MyObject(), MyObject())
c.foo()
```

This will not:

```
c = MyContainer(MyObject(), InvalidObject(), MyObject())    # setup works
c.foo()    # but this fails because InvalidObject doesn't have a bar() method
```

Note that calling `c.baz()` won't work either, since that method is not defined in the `MyContainer` class.

To translate this example to more closely match your code, both the `foo` and `bar` methods could be renamed `update`. Even though they have the same name, they're defined in different classes, and you shouldn't mix them up. `Group.update` in pygame calls `Sprite.update` (or your Sprite subclass' overloaded implementation of it). It doesn't do the same thing for arbitrary other methods, only the ones that are part of an API it has been written to deal with.

Comment: Oh I see it now. I really appreciate the explanation. It took me a while to study and follow it, but I can see it now.